# python string pattern matching

Tags: python

```
       new_str="@@2@@*##1"
       new_str1="@@3@@*##5##7"
```

How to split the above string in python

```
          for val in new_str.split("@@*"):
            logging.debug("=======")
            logging.debug(val[2:]) // will give 
            for st in val.split("@@*"):
                //how to get the values after ##  in new_str and new_str1
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in new_str and new_str1?  5##7 or just 7?  Try using regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand the question.

Are you trying to split a string by a delimiter? Then use [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> a = "@@2@@*##1"
>>> b = "@@3@@*##5##7"
>>>
>>> a.split("@@*")
['@@2', '##1']
>>> b.split("@@*")
['@@3', '##5##7']
```

Are you trying to strip extraneous characters from a string? Then use [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> c = b.split("@@*")[1]
>>> c
'##5##7'
>>> c.strip("#")
'5##7'
```

Are you trying to remove all the hashes (`#`) from a string? Then use [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> c.replace("#","")
'57'
```

Are you trying to find all the characters after `"##"`? Then use `rsplit` with its optional argument to split only once:

```
>>> a.rsplit("##",1)
['@@2@@*', '1']
```

Comment: your last option to find the value is inferior because it "splits only once" and doesn't work on even the second example. Regular expressions are the way to go here ;)

Comment: @Aaron: well, that depends on what the OP wants! Regex are nice, but they can be overkill, especially for simple problems like this.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what OP wants and this is an ideal job for regex. specifically, "//how to get values after ## in new_str1 and new_str2" Now if there are _only ever going to be one or two copies of "##", then your solution works but why make that assumtion when regex are fast enough.

Comment: `I think it's pretty clear what OP wants` Then you must be psychic